# AttributeError: 'ElectricCar' object has no attribute 'battery_size'

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror

i am learning from the book' "Python crash course a handbook". i have written the code exactly as it is in book but still i m getting error. can you please tell me what is the problem with below code:

i m getting 'AttributeError: 'ElectricCar' object has no attribute 'battery_size''.

class Car:

```
def __init__(self, make, model, year):
    self.make=make
    self.model=model
    self.year=year
    self.odometer_reading = 0

def get_discriptive_name(self):
    long_name= f"{self.year}  {self.make}  {self.model}"
    return long_name.title()

def read_odometer(self):
    """Print a statement showing the car's mileage."""
    print(f"This car has {self.odometer_reading} miles on it.")

def update_odometer(self, mileage):
    """ 
    Set the Odometer reading to the given value.
    Reject the change if it attempts to roll the odometer back.
    """
    if mileage >= self.odometer_reading:
        self.odometer_reading = mileage
    else:
        print("You can't roll back an odometer!")

def increment_odometer(self,miles):
    """Add the given amount to the odometer reading."""
    self.odometer_reading += miles

"""Inheritance from parent/superclass to child/subclass."""
```

class ElectricCar(Car):
"""Represent aspects of a car, specific to electric vehicles."""

```
def __intit__(self,make,model,year):

    super().__init__(make,model,year)
    
    self.battery_size = 75

def describe_battery(self):

    """Print a statement describing the battery size."""

    print(f"This car has a {self.battery_size}-kWh battery.")
```

my_tesla = ElectricCar('tesla','model s', 2009)

print(my_tesla.get_discriptive_name())

my_tesla.describe_battery()

Comment: Typo: `__intit__` needs to be `__init__`. Your initializer is never being run as a result, so the attribute is never set.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ElectricCar(Car):
   def __intit__(self,make,model,year):
      super().__init__(make,model,year)
      self.battery_size = 75

   def describe_battery(self):

       """Print a statement describing the battery size."""

       print(f"This car has a {self.battery_size}-kWh battery.")
```

if you take a look you misspelled the **init** function